# all pandas columns showing up as string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting data from a database, and I suspect all the data in it is simply set to string instead of float,int,etc.  When I import the data into a pandas dataframe, it's all showing up as a string.

```
print("products.dtypes")
product_category_name         object
product_description_lenght    object
product_height_cm             object
product_id                    object
product_length_cm             object
product_name_lenght           object
product_photos_qty            object
product_weight_g              object
product_width_cm              object
dtype: object
```

or

```
print (products.applymap(type))
```

Results in:

```
product_category_name product_description_lenght product_height_cm  \
0             <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
1             <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
2             <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
3             <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
4             <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
...                     ...                        ...               ...   
32946         <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
32947         <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
32948         <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
32949         <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   
32950         <class 'str'>              <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>   

          product_id product_length_cm product_name_lenght product_photos_qty  \
0      <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
1      <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
2      <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
3      <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
4      <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
...              ...               ...                 ...                ...   
32946  <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
32947  <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
32948  <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
32949  <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   
32950  <class 'str'>     <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>      <class 'str'>   

      product_weight_g product_width_cm  
0        <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
1        <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
2        <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
3        <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
4        <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
...                ...              ...  
32946    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
32947    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
32948    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
32949    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
32950    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  

[32951 rows x 9 columns]
```

When I look at the data, there are def. numeric values there.  I've tried to take a value and add 1 to it to no avail.

```
products['test'] = products['product_description_lenght'] + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I've tried str.isnumeric but everything shows up as non-numeric.

Is there anything I can to do to detect numeric values?

Comment: `products['product_description_lenght'].astype(float)`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: @JoranBeasley I got this error when I ran that - ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: You can only convert numeric values stored as object to either int or float. Else pandas will throw 'could not convert string' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below:

```
import numbers
products['test'] = pd.to_numeric(products['product_description_lenght'], errors='ignore').apply(lambda x: x + 1 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number) else x)
```

Comment: When I ran the first command, I got this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: When I ran the last command, I got AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

Comment: @Lostsoul Use `pd.to_numeric` not `df.to_numeric`

Comment: @Lostsoul Try just copying my code to the interpreter and run it

Comment: You can only convert numeric values stored as object to either int or float. Else pandas will throw 'could not convert string' error

Comment: When I ran the updated command, I got this error - TypeError: to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'

Comment: @Lostsoul Edited try again

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica I think it worked! I would just loop through it to detect the numerics I guess?